# How can I pass an argument from ngRoute to a function inside the resolve object?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have the following route and resolve object with a function all_data:

```
.when('/events', {
    controller: eventCtrl,
    templateUrl: 'some/path.html',
    resolve:{
        all_data: function(){

        }
```

My question is, if I pass some parameter to the route like this:

```
.when('/events/:param1'), {
....
```

can I somehow pass this "param1" into the "all_data" function like this:

```
....
resolve: {
all_data: function(param1){
    console.log(param1);
}
...
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that the `$routeParams` are only updated *after* a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on `$routeParams` being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use `$route.current.params` to access the new route's parameters.

-- [AngularJS $routeParams API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really worked better. Otherwise I was thinking of how to use callbacks after receiving the $routeParams object. It really didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your resolve method like this assiuming you are using `ngRoute` and the url is like `'/events/:param1'`

```
all_data: ['$routeParams', function($routeParams){
    console.log($routeParams.param1);
}
```

Use `$stateParams` instead of `$routeParams` if you are using ui-router.

Comment: Thanks, it was a great help to me. Unfortunately I can't rate you up, since I myself do not have the necessary points to vote.

Another thing: 
You have forgotten to insert the closing square bracket at the end:

all_data: ['$routeParams', function($routeParams){
    console.log($routeParams.param1);
}]